# Show image in imageview from gallery in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in IOS and i want to show image in imageView which is picked from gallery.And i have also added the photo description in info.plist.But image is not showing in imageView.Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked() {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            //imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            img.image = pickedImage
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: your delegate `imagePickerController`  is called or not

Comment: Remove private and try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using **Swift 3.x**:

You should implement [imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        //imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        img.image = pickedImage
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And it should be good to go. What are the differences? well:

**1-** Remove `private`.

**2-** The signature of the method is not the same, as mentioned in the documentation, `info` should be of type `[String : Any]` *not* `[String : AnyObject]`.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani yes, that's right; I assume that's the reason of why the method is not being called...

Comment: @rachnasharma when you removed `private`, does it work? if yes, then I assume that your are using Swift 2.x... What's the version of your Xcode?

Comment: No its not works fine after removed private.....it works fine when i replaced my code with your code...my xcode version is Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)